# Android Studio: how long does it take for emulator to start first time?

Tags: android-emulator

Have been waiting for over 30 mins now for start for first time.
Its stuck at loading. Should I give up after 40 mins? Looking into installing  Genymotion now.

Installed all sdk, jdk, emulator eccelerator. I use newboston youtube android tutorials.

How long did it take for you to run android emulator for first time?

Comment: It depends on the ram you have given to your emulator. Giving more ram to it, increases the time for it to load. Use minimum 256 MB or if necessary use 512 MB. And adding some more point to your question, sorry to say but Android Development is off-topic here.

Comment: @Gulam Emulator use is on-topic as long as it doesn't go into development issues.  Stella: Yes, that is too long and you might not have powerful enough hardware.

Comment: @MatthewRead, but if we look ahead then it will results into android app development only, that's why..Apology for my comment..